# FAcebook like button -the meaning of the number near it

Tags: facebook-like

> What makes up the number shown on my Like button? The number shown is
>   the sum of:
>
> •The number of likes of this URL
>   •The number of shares of this URL
>   (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
>   •The number of
>   likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
>   •The number
>   of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.

Ok, now if user A likes something, and then user A shares the URL, will I have 2 likes displayed near the button? Or each user can only be counted once

Thanks, I try to understand this because I need to write an app around it

Answer (score 0):

Facebook have a pretty good guide and API for this if you do want to make use of it.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

As far as the process goes, this explanation is better than anything I could come up with. But the long and short of it is, the more people who click on it independently, the more it will increment (See below). Therefore in your example user A likes it (+1), he shares it but only when his friend clicks like when it increment again.

http://www.adsforfacebook.com/the-facebook-like-button.php